# How to get Body element height dynamically using JQuery

Tags: jquery, browser, resize, height, width

I need to get the body element height and width, when i resize the browser windows

Please help me to solve this problem using JQuery

Comment: It's not a good idea to resize browser windows. It's a one of the most common user annoyances.

Comment: He is not trying to resize the browser window using code. He needs to get the height and width when the browser window is resized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the resize event on the window object:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(document).width(), // or $(window).width()
      height = $(document).height(); // or $(window).height()
});
```

Comment: Hi CMS, When u try to alert those height and width it alerts the values atleast 4 times... why is that so??
This happened in chrome browser

Comment: This event might fire several times, while you are resizing the window

Comment: That's right. In IE especially, the resize event is triggered continuously as the window is being resized. Use a combination of setTimeout and clearTimeout with a short delay to prevent triggering multiple events

Comment: Here's a nice implementation of what I mentioned above - http://www.matts411.com/post/delaying_javascript_event_execution/