# Dynamically give elements width/height properties based on browser size

Tags: jquery

How can I give a set of elements (`.div-1`, `.div-2`, `.div-3.` for example) the same dimensions as the browser window?

So if a user's browser window is 1100px wide and 750px high then `.div-1`, `.div-2`, `.div-3` would also each be 1100px wide x 750px high...

Comment: if you give 3 elements same width n height as window, they will overlap

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated, they're going to stack on top of one another. It's a one page kind of layout

Comment: Here you have answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298026/how-to-get-body-element-height-dynamically-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

you can use `width:100%` and `height:100%` in CSS

If they are going to stack on top..this can work as well...`'height:33%'`

Comment: assuming the elements are are top level

Answer (score 1):

To get the height and width of the window (http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
var w = $(window).width() + 'px';
var h = $(window).height() + 'px';
```

To set (http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('.your_divs').css({ "width" : w, "height" : h });
```

Use resize if you need them to resize with your window size changing (http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // reset width and height
});
```

Assuming you are only looking for a jquery answer and your elements isn't top level elements, makes no difference if it is

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can set div attributes using `.height()` and `.width()`.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#div-1").height("100%");
    $("#div-1").width("100%");
});
```

This will adjust the size of `div-1` every time the window is resized so that it fits the current height/width of the browser.  I'd also take a look at CSS/Javascript tools such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html), which offer simple, responsive page frameworks that easily adjust to fit the viewer's screen.

Answer (score 0):

set it to `position: absolute;` and `top/ right/ bottom/ left` properties to `0`

and no need for a jquery